# Flip two columns only under certain condition (for meta-analysis)

Tags: bash, awk

To perform meta-analysis between cohorts, I need to have all alleles coded in the same way.

To do so, these are the steps to follow:

- For each SNP, determine if the alleles match (i.e. `A1` is the same in both cohorts, `A2` is the same in both cohorts).
- If the alleles match, don't do anything
- If the alleles for the SNP don't match (i.e. they are flipped), flip the alleles and flip the sign of the effect-size (column `BETA`)
- If the alleles for the SNP are different, remove the SNP

Cohort 1 (cohort1.txt)

```
SNP     CHR     A1      A2      BP      P       BETA 
SNP1    1       C       T       74648   0.224   0.32 
SNP2    4       A       T       82193   0.345   0.04 
SNP3    5       T       C       34223   0.234   -0.12
SNP4    6       AA      G       31871   0.241   0.043
```

Cohort 2 (cohort2.txt)

```
SNP     CHR     BP      A1      A2      BETA    P
SNP1    1       74648   C       T       0.32    0.224
SNP2    4       82193   A       T       0.04    0.345
SNP3    5       34223   C       T       -0.12   0.234
SNP4    6       31871   A       G       0.13   0.003
```

The "flipped" output for cohort 2 would be:

```
SNP     CHR     BP      A1      A2      BETA    P
SNP1    1       74648   C       T       0.32    0.224
SNP2    4       82193   A       T       0.04    0.345
SNP3    5       34223   T       C       0.12    0.234
```

To get the list of the non-flipped SNPs, I would use:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{_[$3]=$4} NR!=FNR{if($4==_[$5]) print;}' cohort2.txt cohort1.txt
```

Then, to flip the alleles in cohort 2 I would use:

```
awk ' { t = $4; $4 = $5; $5 = t; print; } ' cohort2.txt
```

And finally, to change the sign of the effect-size:

```
awk '{$6=$6*a;print}' a=-1 cohort2.txt
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this only if the initial condition (the alleles match) is wrong.

Comment: Is the `AA` in the last line of cohort1 correct or a typo? ;-) Thanks for fixing your data! Good luck.

Comment: The `AA` is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following, tested with provided samples only. This compares SNPs as per their line numbers, let me add one which works without line number too in few mins.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a2_1[FNR]=$3
  a2_2[FNR]=$4
  next
}
(a2_1[FNR]==$4 && a2_2[FNR]==$5){
  print
  next
}
(a2_1[FNR]==$5 && a2_2[FNR]==$4){
  tmp=$4
  $4=$5
  $5=tmp
  $(NF-1)*=-1
  print
  next
}
(a2_1[FNR]!=$4 && a2_2[FNR]!=$5){
  next
}'  Input_file1  Input_file2 | column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
SNP   CHR  BP     A1  A2  BETA  P
SNP1  1    74648  C   T   0.32  0.224
SNP2  4    82193  A   T   0.04  0.345
SNP3  5    34223  T   C   0.12  0.234
```

---

---

***2nd Solution:*** This is not bounded by row number, $1(SNP) could come in any place in Input_file and it will look for it in Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a2_1[$1,"A1"]=$3
  a2_2[$1,"A2"]=$4
  next
}
(a2_1[$1,"A1"]==$4 && a2_2[$1,"A2"]==$5){
  print
  next
}
(a2_1[$1,"A1"]==$5 && a2_2[$1,"A2"]==$4){
  tmp=$4
  $4=$5
  $5=tmp
  $(NF-1)*=-1
  print
  next
}
(a2_1[$1,"A1"]!=$4 && a2_2[$1,"A2"]!=$5){
  next
}
' Input_file1  Input_file2 | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`, assuming A1 and A2 are of equal length (here 1 char)

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3$4; next} 
                   $1 in a {if(a[$1]==$4$5) print; 
                            else if(a[$1]==$5$4) 
                                    {$6=-$6; t=$4;$4=$5;$5=t; print}}' file1 file2 

SNP     CHR     BP      A1      A2      BETA    P
SNP1    1       74648   C       T       0.32    0.224
SNP2    4       82193   A       T       0.04    0.345
SNP3    5       34223   T       C       0.12    0.234
```